# Richardson extrapolation for second derivative

Tags: numerical-methods, extrapolation

So we know what the Richardson Extrapolation for a first derivative looks like using a recursive formula like this:
$$ D_{m\Delta x}^{1}=\frac{f(x+m\Delta x)-f(x-m\Delta x)}{2m\Delta x}$$
$$ D_{m\Delta x}^{n}=\frac{4^{n-1}D_{m\Delta x}^{n-1}-D_{2m\Delta x}^{n-1}}{4^{n-1}-1}+\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^{2n})$$
for integers $ m,n >0$, where bigger $n$ means greater precision of the derivative.

After learning this formula for a first derivative I tried to reach a similar formula for a second derivative so I started by defining :
$$ \Lambda_{m\Delta x}^{1}=\frac{f(x+m\Delta x)+f(x-m\Delta x)-2f(x)}{m^2\Delta x^2}$$ 
Assuming this, the next step was to get $\Lambda_{m\Delta x}^{2}$ and see if I could extract some kind of pattern so I could get the most generic formula. After some calculations I got ( what I did here was eliminating the term with $\Delta x^4$ so I could raise the precision to $\Delta x^6$):
$$\Lambda_{m\Delta x}^{2}=\frac{4\Lambda_{m\Delta x}^{1}-\Lambda_{2m\Delta x}^{1}}{4-1}+\frac{-4f(x)}{3m^2\Delta x^2}+ \mathcal{O}(\Delta x^{4}) $$ 
We can clearly see that the first fraction is given by the exact same formula as the first derivative, but I also got another term which I believe should not be there ( at this point I'm pretty sure I didn't mess up at any intermediate step) and

Furthermore, I made a little script in Matlab where I didn't put the extra term and I got what I was supposed to:a pretty precise value for the second derivative of any function. Also this extra term "destroys" the rest of the function for when $\Delta x$ is small ( which should be if we want more precision) it goes to infinity.

Basically I reached the conclusion : $ \Lambda_{m\Delta x}^{n}=\frac{4^{n-1}\Lambda_{m\Delta x}^{n-1}-\Lambda_{2m\Delta x}^{n-1}}{4^{n-1}-1}$ for a second derivative.

So my question is if this conclusion is correct ( and why does this term appear and if it shouldn't, should we be able to get another formula like this one for a third order derivative or higher)?

Comment: There shouldn't be any extra term; the Richardson extrapolation of a method $T_n$ with order $p_n$ achieved by considering a method with one step size and another with double that step size is $T_{n+1}(\Delta x)=\frac{2^{p_n} T_n(\Delta x)-T_n(2\Delta x)}{2^{p_n}-1}$.

Comment: (Cont.) The question that Richardson extrapolation needs answered and cannot answer by itself is "what is $p_n$"? The answer comes from the asymptotic expansion of $T_1$. It turns out that if $T_1$ is the usual centered difference then its asymptotic expansion contains all even powers and no odd powers. Thus $p_n=2n$, so $T_{n+1}(\Delta x)=\frac{4^n T_n(\Delta x)-T_n(2\Delta x)}{4^n-1}$. This is equivalent to the first term of what you wrote if you consider the centered difference rule to be $T_0$ instead of $T_1$ (so it is just an indexing discrepancy).

Comment: @Ian This is a pretty good answer actually, thanks for the insight on this topic! I didn't know we could used this formula for a generic method $T_{n}$ that's why I was a bit surprised when i found out the second derivative was just the "same" as the first! Cheers

Comment: You're welcome. The fact that the constants are the same is somewhat of a coincidence; it is caused by the choice of the methods that you used. If you had used, say, $\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ as your base method for the first derivative, then the situation would be different, because in this case *all* powers appear in the asymptotic expansion, so you would have $p_n=n$. Also, would you like me to write up the above comments into an answer?

Comment: @Ian sure! I think it would be great if you could do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any extra term; the Richardson extrapolation of a method $T_n$
with order $p_n$ achieved by considering a method with one step size and another with double that step size is $T_{n+1}(\Delta x)=\frac{2^{p_n}T_n(\Delta x)−T_n(2 \Delta x)}{2^{p_n}-1}$.

The question that Richardson extrapolation needs answered and cannot answer by itself is "what is $p_n$?" The answer comes from the asymptotic expansion of $T_1$. It turns out that if $T_1$ is the usual centered difference then its asymptotic expansion contains all even powers and no odd powers. Thus $p_n=2n$, so $T_{n+1}(\Delta x)=\frac{4^n T_n(\Delta x)−T_n(2\Delta x)}{4^n−1}$. This is equivalent to the first term of what you wrote (in your notation the base rule is $T_0$ rather than $T_1$).

As it happens, when the base rule is the basic centered difference for the first derivative or the centered difference for the second derivative, you have $p_n=2n$, so the same formulae wind up being used.

Comment: The order $p_n$ of the primary error term can be determined experimentally. Specifically, Richardson's fraction $\frac{T_{n}(2\Delta x)-T_{n}(4\Delta x)}{T_{n}(\Delta x)-T_{n}(2\Delta x)}$ will converge (ultimately) monotonically toward $2^p$ and the deviation from $2^p$ is $O((\Delta x)^{q-p})$ where $q$ is the order of the secondary error term in the asymptotic error expansion. Moreover, the region where the computed values of Richardson's fraction behave as the exact values would tends to coincide with the region where the error estimates are reliable.